# What should I do to read dbf file and insert data to Oracle db?

Tags: python, database, oracle, exe, dbf

What language (which programming) should I use to develop an .exe file to read dbf file and insert datas from it to oracle db??

The program will have a button.

I want to make a program that reads a dbf file saved in C drive and excute a query to insert datas of the dbf file to oracle db.

I learned web service is not an option since it cannot fetch files from one's computer.

My purpose is to upload datas to server which is made and saved in one's computer. Therefore, datas can be shared to public(web) by acessesing DB.

I found in google python can be an option.

Please give me a hint if you have the same experience or know the answer.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "a dbf file"?  There are several file formats that conventionally use the dbf extension.  It is common to use the dbf extension for Oracle database files but I seriously hope you're not trying to write a program to upload a random Oracle data file to an Oracle database-- that isn't going to go well for you unless you're a team with several man-years of time on your hands to reverse engineer the Oracle data file format.

Comment: Assuming you're referring to a different dbf file format, and there is a python library that parses that file format, you can certainly write a python script that parses the file and loads the data.  You could run that either on the client machine or on an app server if someone uses a web service to upload their file to the app server.